# Cannot find control with name, first time opening mat dialog

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-forms

I am getting this error

```
main.d6f3e40c71733c3e7aa5.js:1 ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name: 'email'
```

Only on chrome. The form is inside an angular material dialog. I use an injected global service to initialize the form, so before I click the button that opens the modal, the form inside the service is already initialized and if I console.log it I can see the control there.

When I open the mat dialog it is using the service to get the fields as follows:

```html
            <div [formGroup]="loginService.loginForm" class="registration-type-form-container login-form">
                <div
                    *ngIf="loginService.loginForm.invalid && (loginService.loginForm.dirty || loginService.loginForm.touched) && loginService.loginForm.errors && loginService.loginForm.errors.incorrect"
                    class="incorrect-email">
                    {{'login.validation.email-or-pass'|translate}}
                </div>
                <div class="form-container" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center stretch" fxLayoutGap="5px">
                    <div class="e-mail form-input-container" fxFlex="">
                        <input [placeholder]="'login.email' | translate" autocomplete="off"
                               class="email-address form-input" formControlName="email"
                               id="email" required="required">
                        <div *ngIf="email.invalid && (email.dirty || email.touched)" class="requirements"
                             id="login-email">
                            <div *ngIf="email.errors.required">
                                {{'login.validation.email.required' | translate}}
                            </div>
                            <div *ngIf="email.errors.email">
                                {{'login.validation.email.email' | translate}}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
               </div>
```

The input

```html
    <input [placeholder]="'login.email' | translate" autocomplete="off"
                               class="email-address form-input" formControlName="email"
```

is the one throwing the error.

If I close the dialog and reopen it, it does not throw the error again. It only happens the first time. And as I said it only happens in chrome. I tested in firefox and it works fine.
                               id="email" required="required">

Comment: Check this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60221545/add-formcontrol-accroding-to-the-data-returned-from-backend-but-got-two-differen/60222524#60222524

Comment: It seems like the browser is not capturing the changes implicitly. What i can suggest is that you can use the ChangeDetectorRef class and use the detectChanges(). This you can try doing where you are setting the values to the form. It will explicitly force angular to check for changes. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be related to chrome version 80.

Look here for fixes: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/35190

Or follow [Add FormControl accroding to the data returned from backend but got two different error in Angular app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60221545/add-formcontrol-accroding-to-the-data-returned-from-backend-but-got-two-differen/60222524#60222524)